# How can I combine Windows paths and wildcards?

Tags: c#, git-bash

I often have a Windows absolute path (e.g. `C:\test`) in my clipboard and I want to paste it into `git-bash`.  This normally works if I put the path in single quotes:

```
$ ls 'C:\test'
bar.txt   foo.txt  baz.exe  dat.exe
```

My problem is when I try to add a wildcard to the path:

```
$ ls 'C:\test\*.txt'
ls: cannot access 'C:\test\*.txt': No such file or directory

$ ls 'C:\test\'*.txt
ls: cannot access 'C:\test\*.txt': No such file or directory
```

I know it will work if I transform the path to Unix-style, i.e. `/c/test/*.txt`, but that's not very convenient, since I already have the Windows path in the clipboard.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can understand, It's very inconvenient to not being able to use  regex with `ls` :> . you can try this workaround `ls 'C:\test\' | grep txt$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a console app in C# that switches the path in the clipboard between Windows and `git-bash`.  I just get a path into the clipboard, run this app, and it updates the clipboard to have the opposite style path.  Then I just paste.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SwitchPath
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private const RegexOptions Options =
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant |
            RegexOptions.Multiline;

        private static readonly Regex WinPath = new Regex(
            @"^([a-z]):\\(.+)$", Options);

        private static readonly Regex UnixPath = new Regex(
            @"^/([a-z])/(.+)$", Options);

        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            var path = Clipboard.GetText().Trim();
            string drive, rest;

            var m = WinPath.Match(path);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                drive = m.Groups[1].Value.ToLowerInvariant();
                rest = m.Groups[2].Value.Trim().Replace(@"\", "/");
                path = $"/{drive}/{rest}";
                Clipboard.SetText(path);
                return;
            }

            m = UnixPath.Match(path);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                drive = m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpperInvariant();
                rest = m.Groups[2].Value.Trim().Replace("/", @"\");
                path = $@"{drive}:\{rest}";
                Clipboard.SetText(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! It would be even nicer if you could figure out WHO is getting the clipboard text and convert it in-flight! :)